# Android Studio execution error message

Tags: android-studio

A test project is created in Android Studio. Then immediately clicked on run or debug.

The following message pos up:

```
'Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
Failed to create D:\Project\Android\Asd\app\build\source\buildConfig\debug\com1\example\app`
```

One thing I found that Java folder is empty. But in the tutorial a default file is created by the IDE. Unfortunately here it is missing. If more information is needed please post it here.
What I am missing, please help me.

*****Sorry for the trouble. In response to the message:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to create D:\Project\Android\Asd\app\build\source\buildConfig\debug\com1\example\app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.994 secs
```

Comment: something related to UAC permissions maybe ? Android Studio is still in beta anyway, keep this in mind.

Comment: What do you get in the Gradle console window?

Comment: *Please see my original post @user2485710, its mentioned below. Space resection, sorry for that trouble.

Comment: Try building from the command line. From the project's root directory (where you should see a gradlew.bat file), use this command and paste the output in your question: gradlew.bat assembleDebug --info --stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be because Windows won't let you name folders COM1, COM2, etc.  I had to navigate to app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml.  Then, I edited the AndroidManifest.xml file package value to take out the number after 'com'.  So for you, change package=com1... to package=com..., then try re-compiling (Build > Make Project, or CTRL + F9.)

Example of the AndroidManifest.xml file that you need to edit:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourdomain.httpssubdomain.yourappname >`

List of forbidden names:

> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396